# "Operation not permitted" when trying to save file to internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to save a file to internal storage on android so it will be visible in the file manager on the phone. When I try to save it I get "Operation not permitted" error, guessing it has something to do with permissions but not sure what to do. I have added permissions to the android_manifest file but it still doesn't work.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void gen(View view){
        Log.i("CLICKED", "CLICKED");
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(date);
        Log.i("DATE", dateTime);

        String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i("DIR4", dir);

        File file = new File(dir, "TEXT"+dateTime+".txt");
        try{
            file.createNewFile();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And in the android_manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.x_gen_15">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.x_gen_15">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The error shows:

```
2021-06-29 17:21:37.656 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
2021-06-29 17:21:37.656 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at com.example.pdf_gen_15.MainActivity.gen(MainActivity.java:41)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.657 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.659 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.659 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.659 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.659 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.660 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.660 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.661 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.661 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-06-29 17:21:37.662 11189-11189/com.example.x_gen_15 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10154; state: ENABLED
```

***UPDATE***

Someone suggested requesting permission at run time, which I did with code below, but it still shows same error:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 411);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) says you need to ask permission to the user. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) you have some Kotlin and Java code with examples to request permission.

Comment: it still doesn't work. there is only permission for external storage. I need the file to appear in the file manager.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit too late, but the cause is a ":" char (from the timestamp) in the name of the created file. Android 11 (unlike older Android versions) does not allow that.

Comment: Great fix for an edge case, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the help anyway. never finished the project but i'm learning kotlin now instead.